# replace class of span tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I am trying to replace a class from a span tag using jquery. Could somebody tell me what the problem is. When I change it through the browser tools it works ok. Not able to get is working via jquery

```
if ($('#RequestID').val().length <= 0) {

            $(".newRequestDetail > ul > li > a.span").removeClass('.k-icon k-panelbar-expand k-i-arrow-s').addClass('.k-icon k-panelbar-expand k-i-lock');

            var panelbar = $("#panelBar").data('kendoPanelBar');
            panelbar.bind('select', function (e) {
              panelbar.clearSelection();


            });
        }
```

CSS

[image]

Comment: a.span means an anchor with class of "span", try $(".newRequestDetail > ul > li > a > span")

Comment: Thanks it worked. Silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to add space between the 'a' selector and '.span' selector since they are not sharing the same HTML tag.

```
$(".newRequestDetail > ul > li > a. span").removeClass('.k-icon k-panelbar-expand k-i-arrow-s').addClass('.k-icon k-panelbar-expand k-i-lock');
```

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way would be to use:

`$("a.k-link > span").removeClass('k-i-arrow-s').addClass('k-i-lock');`

With this you're specifically targeting the `<a>` tag with class `k-link` and I've removed the additional class removal/adding as looks like you were removing then adding the same classes (`k-icon k-panelbar-expand`) when you only actually need to remove `k-i-arrow-s` and then add `k-i-lock`

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code.

- The selector `$(".newRequestDetail > ul > li > a.span")` needs to change to `$(".newRequestDetail > ul > li > a span")`
- The dot before `k-icon` needs to go away both for `removeClass` and `addClass`

Please try this:

```
    if ($('#RequestID').val().length <= 0) {

            $(".newRequestDetail > ul > li > a span").removeClass('k-icon k-panelbar-expand k-i-arrow-s').addClass('k-icon k-panelbar-expand k-i-lock');

            var panelbar = $("#panelBar").data('kendoPanelBar');
            panelbar.bind('select', function (e) {
                panelbar.clearSelection();    
            });
        }
```